# How to return from sourced bash script automatically on any error?

Tags: bash, return

I have a bash script which is only meant to used be when sourced. 
I want to return from it automatically on any error, similar to what `set -e` does.
However setting `set -e` doesn't work for me because it will also exit the users shell.

Right now I'm handling returning manually like this `command || return 1`, for each command.

Comment: aside: `somecommand || return` will return the exit status of the command that failed, which is arguably more useful than hardcoding `1`. (`command` being the name of an actual builtin command, btw, it's not ideal for use as a placeholder).

Comment: ...that said, `set -e` is [prone to nonintuitive and surprising behaviors](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (skip the allegory and try to answer the exercises below if in a hurry) and has [wildly different and incompatible implementations between different shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/). What you're doing right now -- `|| return` over and over -- is arguably the Right Thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `command || true` or `command || return`.
If your requirement is something different, please update more precisely.

Comment: `command || return 1` - that's what I'm doing now and looking for a way to automate it. (I originally wrote `command || exit 1` in my main post, edited)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trap`. E.g.:

```
// foo.sh
function func() {
    trap 'if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then  echo "Trapped!"; return ; fi' DEBUG
    echo 'foo'
    find -name "foo" . 2> /dev/null
    echo 'bar'
}

func
```

Two notes. First, the `trap` needs to be inside the function as shown. It won't work if it's just inside the script.

Two, there is a significant limitation. Even if you set the return to the trap (e.g., `return 1`), while `func` exists after the bad `find` command, `$?` is still zero, no matter what. I'm not sure if there's a way around that, so if it's important to preserve the exit value of the failed command, this may not work.

E.g., if you had:

```
func
func_return=$?
echo "return value is: $func_return"
```

`func_return` will always be zero. I've played around with trying to get the exit value of the failed command to pass out of the function trap and into the function exit value, but have not found a way to do it.

If you need to preserve the return value, you could update a global variable inside the debug trap.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you can set -e locally in each function.

```
cat sourced

f1 () {
  local -
  set -e
  [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2> /dev/null && echo "$1"
}

cat script.sh

. sourced
param='bad'
ret=$(f1 "$param")
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "result = $ret" || \
  echo "error in sourced file with param $param"
param=3
ret=$(f1 "$param")
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "result = $ret" || \
  echo "error in sourced file with param $param"
```

Comment: Putting a `&&` after a simple command makes it "checked", so `set -e` ignores it. You're only seeing a nonzero exit status returned because `$?` at function's end is the exit status of the `[` command, *because when `&& echo` doesn't execute that's the last command in the function anyhow*.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/wzd9KT -- notice that `f2` has an exit status of `0` despite the `set -e`.